# Way to Cover Up Or Blur Crease / Ridge In Blender

Tags: modeling, smooth

[Following this tutorial](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Blender-3D-Your-First-3D-Character/527979685/projects?via=user-profile) and using a mirror modifier, specifically, I was able to create this little bird in Blender

[image]

But as you can see, there's an obnoxious crease right down the middle and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've tried to line up the vertices in the center as best as possible. And when I try to overlap them, it only makes the crease worse.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to fix this in Blender? A way to smooth over the crease somehow? Almost like blurring in Photoshop. Thanks!

Comment: In Edit mode go into x-ray mode (Shft-Z) and see if there's an internal face down the middle of the object. If so, select and delete it. Also enable Clipping in the mirror modifier.

Comment: Incidentally the link to that tutorial requires registration and/or payment so no-one here will be able to view itl.

Comment: Sorry about that. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/SQKu89n.png) of the model in x-ray mode. I don't see an internal face down the middle. And I did [enable Clipping in the mirror modifier](https://i.imgur.com/GnsZsez.png), but it didn't seem to have any effect (?)

Comment: Here is a link to download the file if you're interested [https://pasteall.org/blend/fee578105ab54ccd92fba1b00151b824](https://pasteall.org/blend/fee578105ab54ccd92fba1b00151b824)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just raise the merge value

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: I agree that will get rid of most of the crease, but it's really masking quite a few other problems in the model, not least being the fact that the 3D cursor isn't in the centre of the world and the object's origin is offset from the cursor. Also,the 'loose parts' (beak, wing and eye) seem to have been joined to the body before the mirror modifier was added so are overlapping in places.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes there are in fact still plenty of issues with this model, which are now becoming apparent during texturing. I.e. when I try to color the beak, it's drawing on the head as well and same thing with the eyes. [https://pasteall.org/blend/d34b9f0c42064934870e9f2b1603fbbe](https://pasteall.org/blend/d34b9f0c42064934870e9f2b1603fbbe)

Comment: Without being able to see the original tutorial it's not really possible to offer any suggestions I'm afraid.